# jQuery fadeTo - how to use

Tags: javascript, jquery

First I want to say that I am new in learning jQuery and I am trying to create a slideshow using it.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Slider li img").click(function() {
        $("").fadeTo('slow',0);
        $('#mainImg').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
    });

    var imgSwap = [];
    $("#Slider li img").each(function() {
        imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
        imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
    });
    $(imgSwap).preload();
});

$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each( function() { $('<img/>')[0].src = this; }); 
}
```

And my divs:

```
<div id="Slider"> 
    <img src="sliderImg/img_1.png" alt="" id="mainImg" />
    <ul>
        <li><img src="sliderImg/thumb/img_1.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="sliderImg/thumb/img_2.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="sliderImg/thumb/img_3.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="sliderImg/thumb/img_4.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="sliderImg/thumb/img_5.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="sliderImg/thumb/img_6.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="sliderImg/thumb/img_7.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="sliderImg/thumb/img_8.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="sliderImg/thumb/img_9.png" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to make transitions between the images.
How can I do such a thing? I tried to use the `fadeTo()` function but I could not succeed.

Thanks for help

Comment: The fadeTo() method is intended to do partial opacity transitions. For a slideshow you probably want fadeIn(), fadeOut(), or fadeToggle(), which transition from full opacity to zero opacity and vice versa. That said, what's not working? Please be more specific.

Comment: can u create a js fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your `$("").fadeTo('slow',0);` can't work, because you are not targeting any element.

You could use `$(this).fadeTo('slow', 0);` or any other selector.

Answer (score 0):

fadeTo is not used for fading to a different element, it is used for fading to a different style for one element.

You can fade one element out and the fade in another to do what you are after.

Comment: Well how can ı give the transitinon ? or which function is used for it ?

Comment: fadeOut and fadeIn would be better used here

Comment: Check out these slideshows and dig around in their code to see whats going on; http://www.webtuts.info/webdesigning/jquery-slideshow-tutorial-beginners/933/

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all images, and store them in a array. 
Show the first one. 
When clicking showing the next one (going one step in the array) 
and hiding the rest. 
Then so forth. 
The rest is just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have highlighted the problems in your code but you could consider using a slideshow plugin for JQuery as an alternative to writing your own slideshow. You may find it easier to use a plugin to achieve the effect you are after.  You can browse the slideshow plugins on JQuery's plugin website here: http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/slideshow/ 
There are also many blogs that list the "best jquery slideshow plugins" to be found with Google.